# How do you add clients to your Clockify workspace with the POST command?

Tags: powershell, api, clockify

Is there any way of using the POST command in PowerShell to add clients to my Clockify workspace?

Clockify has an API so I wonder how to do this. Anybody has experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to `POST` to a `REST` endpoint:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri 'rest api uri' -Credential 'credentials to endpoint' -Headers 'headers passed' -Body 'Content Body' -ContentType 'text? json? xml?'`

For more details: [Read the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7)